# How to find grant opportunities for academic position?

Tags: research-proposal

I am a senior Ph.D. student in software security in Germany. I am looking for some grants for my postdoc. I have a proposal ready, but I do not know good enough about the grant opportunities. So, I think that I need to submit my proposal to many places to increase the chance of obtaining a good grant? What do you think? Is any neat database for finding the grants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many grants that US researchers have will included salary or partial salary for postdoctoral researcher(s) that they want to include the work of. You might just checkout the websites of professors, centers, or labs that you'd like to work for and see if they are hiring a postdoc. Those are probably already funded for some period of time, and the position announcement may already describe that time-frame. In the US, at my institution, if you came to me and said that you had full funding for a postdoc lined up and just needed me to open slot for you and hire you, I wouldn't be allowed to do it even if you seemed to be the perfect candidate. I'd actually have to be awarded the funding by a funding agency and open an official position at my institution that was open for all qualified applicants to apply to. Then I'd have to follow official application and interview procedures to see who got the position. The fact that you had your own funding would weight towards you, but it wouldn't necessarily guarantee that you'd get it or that the funding agency would give my institution the money to then give to you to pay your salary. If someone more qualified applied, and I had another source of funds to pay them, I'd be required to hire them instead of you to do the job. I would not be allowed to even post the position without a more solid funding stream lined up.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are in Europe, [EURAXESS](https://euraxess.ec.europa.eu/funding/search) (which belongs to the European Commission) may be a suitable platform to you. National funders from the EU (and beyond) regularly list their calls there.

There may also be national databases of research grants (provided by official bodies). For instance, as regards Germany, the DAAD offers this [Scholarship Database](https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/stipendium/datenbank/en/21148-scholarship-database/), while Austria offers a comprehensive and always up-to-date list at [grants.at](https://grants.at/).

The analogy for the U.S. seems to be [grants.gov](https://www.grants.gov/).

Comment: Hopkins in the US has a good list of postdoc funding: https://research.jhu.edu/rdt/funding-opportunities/postdoctoral/